# Retrieve quote from other website in same installation

Tags: magento

I'm attempting what I thought would be simple but has turned complicated.  Basically, I have two websites in one installation.  I need to retrieve the current quote (guest or logged-in) from the opposite website.

The sessions are shared across both.  Here's what I've tried so far:

- Setting the current store to the opposite store briefly, grabbing cart and setting it back.  This actually does work for wishlists but not quotes
- Setting the opposite store in core/session and retrieving quote
- Parsing core/session visitor data for ID I could use to do SQL query. There is a visitor_id but have not found the link between that and quote

Has anyone done this before?  Seems like there should be a way to grab quote using sessionId with storeId but I haven't found it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are using 2 websites for the right reason? I don't think it was ever intended to trade quote info between them.

Comment: maybe 2 different store view but 1 website is better solution for your case

Comment: Thanks but in this case, there are two, very distinct sites.  Only one is eCommerce. The client only decided, after they were built, that they wanted the eCommerce totals on the non-eCommerce site.

Answer (score 0):

Argh, was looking in the wrong session namespace.  Should have been checkout/session (obviously) instead of core/session.  Will go ahead and answer it, in case someone else has same obstacle.

```
$ecommerce = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load('ecommerce_store_view');
$quoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getData('quote_id_' . $ecommerce->getWebsiteId());
```